# Designed template for Joomla is not showing the modules

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I designed a template for Joomla 1.5 and problem is that it is not showing the modules enabled , for example I have created an article and it shows the title and body but it does not show the date or enabled plugins like JComment !!! 
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: [Solved] Problem was in this tag : <jdoc:include type="component" /> and xml file .

Comment: You should add the answer and accept it in case someone else has a similar problem.

Comment: I did not know I can add my own answer , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was in the following tag:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

and XML file.